# Unable to invoke method in mocked service from mocked controller using mockito with spring web mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito, junit4

I am trying to create a JUnit test case for spring mvc rest controller and service that is accessed by controller.
I am using Mockito for doing the above. I'm am able to successfully invoke the mock injected controller from the test case and also when I debug I see that the mocked userService is available in the mocked contoller, but the method within the service object is not getting invoked. While debugging I observe that it just steps over the service method call. 

I do not see any kind of exception too.

I am using

1. Maven 3
2. Spring 4.1.1 Release version
3. Junit 4.11
4. Java version 1.6

I have pasted my code below:

**1. Test Class**

```
    package controller;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
    import org.mockito.Mock;
    import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.myPackage.model.User;
    import com.myPackage.service.IUserService;

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/spring/application-config.xml")
    public class UserControllerTest {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Mock
        private IUserService userService;

        @InjectMocks
        private UserController  controller;

        @Before
        public void setup(){
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
        }

        @Test
        public void testRegisterUser()throws Exception{
            User user = new User();
            user.setCity("City");
            user.setTown("Town");
            user.setFirstname("Name");
            user.setLastname("LastName");
            user.setPassword("abc@123");
            user.setUsername("abc@gmail.com");

            RequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/service/user/register/")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(convertObjectToJsonBytes(user));

            mockMvc.perform(builder).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
        }

        public static byte[] convertObjectToJsonBytes(Object object) throws IOException {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);
        }
    }
```

**2. Controller under Test**

```
    package com.myPackage.controller;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import com.myPackage.model.User;
    import com.myPackage.service.IUserService;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/service/user")
    public class UserController {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

        @Autowired
        private IUserService userService;

        public IUserService getUserService() {
            return userService;
        }

        public void setUserService(IUserService userService) {
            this.userService = userService;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/register/", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
        public String registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
            logger.info("register user:"+user.toString());
            String userDetails = userService.registerUser(user);
            logger.info("user registered:"+userDetails);
            return userDetails;
         }
    }
```

**3. Service to be invoked within controller in test**

The service method registerUser is to be invoked from controller above. I do not see any logs getting printed on the console when we run the test case. Also when debugging I see that userSerivice instance of type like this - IUserService$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$c00081eb is created but when I dig deep all to see the list of methods under mockhandlers registered methods, I only see 'toString' method in the list of invocations. Not sure if this gives some indication on why this method 'registerUser' in the service class below is not getting invoked during test case.

```
package com.myPackage.service;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.myPackage.dao.IUserDao;
import com.myPackage.model.User;
import com.myPackage.model.UserInfo;

@Service("userService")
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);

    @Autowired
    private IUserDao userDao;

    public IUserDao getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(IUserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    public String registerUser(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.info("New User for registration:",user);
        if(user!=null && user.getUsername()!=null){
            User alreadyExist = userDao.getUserByLogin(user.getUsername());
            if(alreadyExist!=null){
                return "userAlreadyExists";
            }
        }
        logger.info("New User for registration complete:",user.getUser_id());
        return null;
    }
}
```

**4. Interface implemented by UserService class in point 3 above**

IUserService. The mocked userService in test class above is of type IUserService.

```
package com.myPackage.service;

import com.myPackage.model.User;
import com.myPackage.model.UserInfo;

public interface IUserService {

    public String registerUser(User user);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method (read code) within userService will never actually be invoked from your controller because, it has been mocked out by mockito.

You have defined this yourself by doing:

```
@Mock
private IUserService userService;

@InjectMocks
private UserController  controller;

MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

If you want to assert that the method has been called you can using,

```
verify(userService, times(1)).registerUser(any(User.class));
```

Comment: :Thanks for your insight. If i don't mock userService then at the time of unit test, userService is found null  under userController method matching registerUser. And so after reading somewhere i mocked userService. Also after doing the changes as suggested by you, the mocked service method still does not get invoked - Below are my changes -                                         
  mockMvc.perform(builder).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
  Mockito.verify(userService, Mockito.times(1)).registerUser(Mockito.any(User.class));

Comment: userService is null because it's probably not available in the spring context. Add a @Component scan for "com.myPackage.service" on your test. For the other issue, it will never be actually invoked when working with mocked objects.

Comment: Thanks again for valuable inputs. Using @ComponentScan("com.myPackage.service") too did not help, service instance was still null in controller under test.But what i understood is if i try to mock then i would to be able to invoke the service because it is just a stub as mentioned by Khalid below. Disappointingly i accept that i cannot invoke the method in service while keeping controller under test. I wish there was a way out since i wanted to check complete flow in one test case.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonas: Thanks for your insight. If i don't mock userService then at the time of unit test, userService is found null  under userController method matching registerUser. And so after reading somewhere i mocked userService. Also after doing the changes as suggested by you, the mocked service method still does not get invoked - Below are my changes -

```
RequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/service/user/register/")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(convertObjectToJsonBytes(user));

mockMvc.perform(builder).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
Mockito.verify(userService, Mockito.times(1)).registerUser(Mockito.any(User.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the actual service method, then autowire it:

```
@Autowired
private IUserService userService;
```

If you want to use a mock like you're doing now, you need to stub the method:

```
when(userService.registerUser(any(User.class))).thenReturn("expected string");
```

Comment: Thanks Khalid for your inputs. @Autowired did not make service class instantiate but stubbing method made me understand that i cannot invoke the method, all i can do is replicate the behavior. Though i wished there was a way to test complete flow from controller to service to dao in single test case.

Comment: You can do that with [integration testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#integration-testing).

Comment: If you check my test class above, i am already following things mentioned in Spring Integration test document. We are loading application context at the start of test, using follwoing code at top of the test class and using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner too- @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/spring/application-config.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class UserControllerTest {}